# Message: Undefined offset: in split function and values are set to array

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
 for ($x = 1; $x <= $num; $x++) {
 $userArray[] = $this->input->post("select" . $x . "");
 }
    $userArray = split(',', $userArray);
$productName = $userArray[0];
$barcode = $userArray[1];
$quantity = $userArray[2];
    $flag = $this->cartmodel->productCategory($category);
 }
```

The main problem in the code is that it is not able to come to $userArray ... it takes it as array....

got a doubt.... m fetching the quantity through text box.. but its not able to get in the array....

```
   <input type="text" name ="Quantity<?=$i;?>" id = "Quantity<?=$i;?>" value=""/></td> 
  <select name="select<?=$i;?>"><option value="">NO</option><option value="<?=$row ->product_name;?>,<?=$row->barcode?>,<?=$i;?>">YES</option>
```

Comment: explode expects string as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php - split takes a string as an argument, not an array.

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= $num; $x++)
{
  $input = $this->input->post("select" . $x . "");
  $row = split(',', $input);
  $productName = (isset($row[0]) ?  $row[0] : '');
  $barcode = (isset($row[1]) ?  $row[1] : '');
  $quantity = $this->input->post("quantity" . $x . "");
  $flag = $this->cartmodel->productCategory($category);
}
```

Comment: Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: got a doubt.... m fetching the quantity through text box.. but its not able to get in the array....                                        <input type="text" name ="Quantity<?=$i;?>" id = "Quantity<?=$i;?>" value=""/></td> <select name="select<?=$i;?>"><option value="">NO</option><option  value="<?=$row ->product_name;?>,<?=$row->barcode?>,<?=$i;?>">YES</option>

Comment: can not help with that without seeing more of your code.  sounds like you need to consider form validation, use of php functions as re-usable code and how you are passing variable around.  it is VERY un-reliable to 'explode' a string if its coming from a text input without strict validation.  If I am enter a "," into your text input, its going to mess up your array indexs.

Comment: just tell me what should be the value in the selectbox .... and its not able to take the quantity in the array
   $quantity = $this->input->post('Quantity'.$x); this can fetch the exact quantity .. should i do concatenation

Comment: sorry bigstylee ... the quantity is not able to fetch in tat loop